# SpaceX estimates for Starship and Super-heavy heat shields maximum heating during their orbital and suborbital reentry

Tags: spacex, rockets

Did SpaceX made public their estimates for Starship orbital vehicle heat shield maximum heating (and overall reentry heating profile) during orbital reentry on Earth and same for Super-heavy booster suborbital reentry after stage separation.

Starship will descent horizontally with ceramic TPS on the bottom, with most intense heating on the leading edges of 4 flaps, nose cone and aft part. It is no longer on SpaceX website, but last time I looked Starship had projected empty mass 120t with 65t return to Earth payload. If you add propellant needed for landing burn, it can be more than twice of Shuttle reentry mass, but Starship has entirely different type of TPS.

Super-heavy booster should descend vertically like F9 booster, with most intense heating on the engine section. Don't remember showing them what could be Super-heavy reentry mass (booster empty mass + mass of propellant needed for return) or if engines section made from S steel will need any additional TPS.

Comment: The booster stages much earlier than Falcon9 does, so reentry heating will be much less. The same solution currently used for Falcom9 will be over-ample for Starship Booster. Starship vs. Shuttle reentry and heatshielding is a long, long topic which I will not touch.

Comment: At what suborbital speed they plan to separate booster from Starship, with F9 it should be about 1.5 km/s. Do they plan any missions where they will need land the booster on drone ships, instead of let it return to launch site (in BCH or ocean launch platforms). Or are they already sure, that they can catch the booster with launch tower and all booster drone ship landings with legs are off table.

Comment: F9 is more like 1.9-2.1 km/s (2.6 if fully expended). Starship booster should be about 1.5-1.6km/s.